# Kerberos, Claims Based authentication and Sharepoint : Cannot connect to database

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, kerberos, claims-based-identity

I have a server which hosts Sharepoint 2010. I have another server which hosts a SQL Server 2008 R2. SharePoint is Kerberos/Claims Based.

On my SharePoint, I installed a custom made webpart that connects to the SQL Server machine using standard connection string (`Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;`).

The problem is that when the webpart tries to connect to the sql server, I get the following message :

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
```

What we've done :

- Verify all spn/delegation/trusts things - everything seems okay.
- Tried to connect directly from the sharepoint machine via a UDL file to sql server, and it works.
- Tried the webpart as standalone ASPX page on a single machine server to prove the code is supposed to work, and it works.
- Wireshark -> We can see a KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN when ANONYMUS LOGON tries to connect to sql server (obvisously).
- SharePoint Developer Dashboard shows us our current username, which is not ANONYMUS.
- Traces in the webpart shows two things : The HTTPCONTEXT is set to my current user, so is the Thread.Current.
- Using SQL Profiler, we can see that the request is from ANONYMUS
- ***We tried to access a web service on another server from another custom made webpart, and it failed for the same reason (ANONYMUS).***

What are we missing? The problem really seems to be that SharePoint is unable to send the current user credential to another server (sql or not).

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that Kerberos is working ?

Download the Troubleshooting Kerberos Delegation

http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=99B0F94F-E28A-4726-BFFE-2F64AE2F59A2&displaylang=en

Comment: Yeah we went through that too. Everything is setup properly. We recently read on a non official source that case could matter in the SPN, so we are checking all of them right now...